# cgi/fastcgi 0% CPU and N% Memory?

Tags: php, iis, wordpress, fastcgi

I have php wordpress website hosted on IIS, have been using FastCGI, below is my fastCGI configuration

[image]

Below is screenshot of task manager

[image]

There are many fastCGI processes that are using 0% CPU but consuming certain portion of RAM, is this ok ? or there is any misconfiguration due to which this is happening

Answer (score 0):

For many processes, read this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-php-applications-on-iis/configure-php-process-recycling-behavior